# jsp 2D array in table

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have a 2D array in java, trying to print it in table form in jsp.
Below code is working -

```
                                <table>
                                    <c:forEach items="${combinations}" var="face">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>${face[0]}</td>
                                            <td>${face[1]}</td>
                                            <td>${face[2]}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </c:forEach>
                                </table>
```

But instead of hard coding index, I need to make it dynamic based on size of array.
Please help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use for lops the same way as in plain java like this:

```
<table>
<%
int[][] arr = { {0,1,2}, {3,4,5}, {6,7,8}};
for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < arr.length; rowIndex++) {
    %><tr><%
    for (int numIndex = 0; numIndex < arr[rowIndex].length; numIndex++) {
        %><td><%= arr[rowIndex][numIndex] %></td><% 
    }
    %></tr><%
}
%>
</table>
```

You just have to make sure that every element of your code is inside a `<% ... %>` statement.

The outhput of this code looks like this:
[image: example]

---

In JSF it could look like this:

```
<c:forEach items="${combinations}" var="rows">
    <tr>
        <c:forEach items="${rows}" var="face">
            <td>${face}</td>
        </c:forEach>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way I can access 'arr' which I have put in model attribute in java code to access inside this scriplet?
Also please suggest if I can achieve it with any modification to the jsp loop I have tried.

Comment: I edited the answer to support your type of for loop. Can you please test it? I don't have a current project I could test it on.